# Flash of pause/rewind icon during video playback

Tags: video, html5-video

Recently I've started seeing a flashing "pause" or "rewind" icon that overlays video content during playback in Chrome on OSX:

[image]

I've tried investigating these videos with the Chrome dev tools to no avail. Does anyone know what might cause that flashing behavior? I'd be very grateful for any ideas others can offer on this question!

Comment: If you have set the height and width attributes of the YT iframe, try assigning the same dimensions in a stylesheet as well. If you have wrapped YT iframe inside a div, ensure there is no padding for the wrapper or margins for the YT iframe.

Comment: @zer00ne Thanks very much for your note. I should have said this occurs on the YT domain, which uses a `<video>` tag...